# How to integrate Selenium with ALM Octane

Tags: selenium, integration, alm

We have recently migrated from HP ALM to ALM Octane, and we have a requirement to integrate Octane with Selenium.

All the automated scripts which we have in Selenium should run and update the Pass/Fail status to Octane.

Can someone please help me with a script to integrate Selenium with Octane?

Comment: What have you tried until now? Did you try any script?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and relevant HTML and the error stack trace.

Comment: I would suggest that you explore ALM Rest API for this purpose. Without any sample code it will be difficult to know where are you stuck